# question about triple integral with spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

Find the volume of the solid E which is located outside the circular cone
$x^2 + y^2 = (z − 1)^2$ and between the planes $z = 0$ and
$z = 2$. 
This is not hard problem as I know. I am trying to convert to E to spherical coordinates and integral.

For that 
$0<\rho<2$, I have trouble to get $\phi$ and $\theta$ algebraically not graphically. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have to do it with the integral or are you allowed to do it geometrically like just writing $\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h$ if you see a finite height cone?

Comment: Yes, I have to do it by integral

Comment: What do you mean by outside the circular cone?

Comment: @gb2017 Do you mean the volume _inside_ the circular cone? Because the volume outside the cone between those two planes is infinite.